# Trigger multi-project build on branch, but only if branch exists

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have projects in many git repositories, starting with the base api and then branching outwards.
When the API materially changes, I want to verify that downstream projects (that use the particular API) work correctly.
I hoped this workflow would be supported out of the box:

1. Make changes on branch to base API
2. Create same named branch on a subset of projects that may be affected by the change
3. Execute the build triggering children with

```
run-A:
  stage: .post
  trigger: 
    project: a
    branch: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    strategy: depend

run-B:
...
```

Sometimes I want to verify A, sometimes B, sometimes both or neither.
If I don't have the same branch in A and B, I start getting

> Downstream pipeline cannot be created; reference cannot be found

How can I get gitlab to depend on the results of other project builds, but ignore the downstream project if the branch doesn't exist?

Comment: Same issue! Did you find a solution? It seems that the variable (even pre-defined ones like in your example (`$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`)) does not work? At least that is what I am seeing. Putting in a constant there i.e, `branch: develop` works. But, I am passing the branch name as a variable to the upstream project.

Comment: related: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/231782